# How to understand auto deduce in for loop?

Tags: c++, type-deduction

Initial value of i don't equal 5, output countless number.

```cpp
int main() {
  vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 1};
  auto size = nums.size();
  for(auto i = 2 * size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // do_stuff()
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `i >= 0` to `i > 0`. `nums.size()` returns `size_type` which is an unsigned type. Decrementing it beyond `0` can lead to garbage values which may not work with your condition.

Comment: [Build with extra warnings enabled](https://godbolt.org/z/G38deWWdT).

Comment: `nums.size()` is unsigned, so `size` is unsigned, so `i` is unsigned, so `i >= 0` is always true and decrementing zero gives you a huge number..

Comment: @Tharsalys Unsigned underflow and overflow are well-defined and don't produce "garbage" (although the results are usually as useful as garbage in context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue stems from the fact that the type of `i` is unsigned, so `i >= 0` is always true, rendering the loop infinite.

`i` is deduced to be of the same type as `size`, and `size` is deduced to be of type `size_t` because `vector::size()` returns `size_t`.

Because of above, and unsigned integer overflow, your loop is infinite. It prints (*)

```
5 4 3 2 1 0 4294967295 4294967294 4294967293 ... 3 2 1 0 4294967295 4294967294 ...
```

to infinity and beyond.

(*) if `size_t` is 32 bits on your platform.

Comment: unsigned integers don't overflow, they wrap around

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number they can overflow if you do 0xFFFFFFFF + 1 with a 32 bit unsigned int, but in this case (0 - 1) I agree wraparound is a better term.

Comment: > so i <= 0 is always true. 
wrong,
so i >= 0 is always true.

Comment: @douyu Yes, typo which already has a suggested edit in the queue

Answer (score 1):

Because `nums.size()` is an `std::size_t`, which is an alias for `unsigned int`, so `size` is `unsigned int`.

`auto i = 2 * size - 1;`, because `size` is an `unsigned int` so the compiler decided to make `i` an `unsigned int`, so `i >= 0` is always true. Trying to decrement it results in a wrap around(to `4294967295`) and decrement it.

Comment: `nums.size()` is a `std::vector<int>::size_type` which isn't an `unsigned int`. It is always unsigned though. Its more likely to be a `size_t`.

Comment: @MikeVine and `size_t` might be just an alias for `unsigned int` ;)